# Move multiple files with wildcards

Tags: bash, mv

I'd like move multiple files with wildcards like

```
mv log.* ./log
mv: rename log to ./log/log: Invalid argument
```

the log.* are listed as:

```
ls log*
log.md  log.txt
```

How could I move them at once?

Comment: Are you sure you ran what you wrote? Or maybe you ran `mv log* ./log`? The syntax you are using seems to be correct. It should not give you that error.

Comment: `mv log.* ./log` this command works for me with two files named `log.md` and `log.txt` and a directory named `log` in current working directory

Comment: Yes, $ mv log.* ./log
mv: rename log.* to ./log/log.*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message basically says, that you can't move the log directory into itself.

Be more specific with your source file names, for example include the dot.

```
mv log.* ./log
```